# How to check specific port status of ufw in shell script?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I want to check the status of a specific port of `ufw` in shell script.

To check the status I wrote like this.

```
ufw status | grep -c "^443\s\+ALLOW"
```

It works now for my usage, but if possible I want to use more stable way.
Is there a better way to check the port status of `ufw`?